# Work-around for enclosing instance ineligible for garbage collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection, inner-classes, anonymous-inner-class

The enclosing instance here isn't eligible for garbage collection as long as the enclosed instance is alive, right?

```
interface Foo<T> {
    T compute();

    default Foo<T> memoize() {
        return new Foo<>() {
            T result = null;

            boolean cached = false;

            @Override
            public T compute() {
                if (!cached) {
                    result = Foo.this.compute();
                    cached = true;
                }
                return result;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Does this solve that problem?

```
interface Foo<T> {
    T compute();

    default Foo<T> memoize() {
        return Foo.memoize(this);
    }

    private static <T> Foo<T> memoize(Foo<T> original) {
        class Bar implements Foo<T> {
            T result = null;

            Foo<T> foo;

            Bar(Foo<T> original) {
                foo = original;
            }

            @Override
            public T compute() {
                if (foo != null) {
                    result = foo.compute();
                    foo = null;
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
        return new Bar(original);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Michael I believe so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, the anonymous inner class 'captures' a reference to the enclosing `Foo` by using `Foo.this`. As the anonymous class keeps this reference indefinitely, the enclosing `Foo` is not eligible for garbage collection until the anonymous class is also eligible.

In the second example, this reference is discarded after `compute` has been called once, so the enclosing class is eligible for garbage collection after that.

See [*Accessing Members of an Enclosing Class*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html#accessing-members-of-an-enclosing-class)

Answer (score 3):

Note that there’s the alternative to use lambda expressions, as lambda expressions only capture values as required, e.g.

```
interface Foo<T> {
    T compute();

    default Foo<T> memoize() {
        AtomicReference<Foo<T>> holder = new AtomicReference<>();
        holder.set(() -> {
               T result = compute();
               holder.set(() -> result);
               return result;
            }
        );
        return () -> holder.get().compute();
    }
}
```

The `holder` initially contains a lambda implemented `Foo<T>` that has a reference to the original `Foo<T>` instance as at will invoke `compute` on the first evaluation, but then, it will replace itself with a new lambda implemented `Foo<T>` that will invariably return the computed value. The new lambda doesn’t even need to evaluate a conditional, as the fact that the value has been computed already is implied.

Note that the holder object doesn’t have to be an `AtomicReference` here, but there is no canonical simple-to-use alternative. Generic arrays can’t be created, so the only alternative that comes into my mind would be a (mutable) list of size 1, e.g. created via `Arrays.asList(null)`.

Comment: my god this is ingenious! I don't even know how to call this, a "mutating" lambda a "self-mutating" lambda? waaaay too smart

Answer (score 0):

No, why would it?

The `Bar` instance inside the `memoize()` function has a field that holds the `Foo` object. Whether you hold it via scoping or via implicit field assignment is irrelevant to garbage collection.

If you want to keep a reference to an object that can be garbage collected, use `WeakReference`/`SoftReference`.

Comment: You missed the `foo = null` instruction in Bar.

Comment: Would've sworn that it wasn't there a moment ago ;) yeah, you're right. In that case, after the field is set to null, the `Foo` can be garbage collected. Static inner classes work exactly like outer classes in that respect.